# I can't push button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

website: (https://www.tiktok.com/signup/phone-or-email/email)
I want to push button "Send code", but nothing happen.
`driver2.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="tiktok-[enter image description here]`
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7LGv.png)1fcfbw8-ButtonSendCode e1gzcpl10"]')

I had tried find by XPATH, CLASS_NAME; tried do click by ActionChains.
But it's not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class for button is dynamic and changes for every run that why its not working ,so you have to  use

```
#//button[text()="Send code"]
driver2.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Send code"]')
```

Also it will only enable after all fields are filled so you should do that before clicking on it